# In splunk How to apply Multiple filter on splunk

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula

in splunk if we want to add multiple filter how can we do that easily .
eg:-

index=indexer  action= Null NOT IP IN (10.34.67.32 , 87.90.32.10.. so on)

Now question is if i have 519 IP which i want to exclude from result how can we do that easily..

I  already tried below code but it was taking  more time to write query

index = indexer action =Null IP!=10.34.67.32 IP!=87.90.32.10 so on..

Answer (score 3):

What I suggest is you create a CSV file of IPs you wish to exclude from your search.

```
IP
10.34.67.32
87.90.32.10
...
```

Create a lookup with this file as the source (refer to https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/Usefieldlookupstoaddinformationtoyourevents ). Let's call the lookup `excluded_ips`.

Now, you can do the following search to exclude the IPs from that file

```
index=indexer action= Null NOT [ | inputlookup excluded_ips | fields IP | format ]
```

The `format` command will change the list of IPs into `((IP=10.34.67.32) OR (IP=87.90.32.10))`. So the expanded search that gets run is

```
index=indexer action= Null NOT ((IP=10.34.67.32) OR (IP=87.90.32.10))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the total IP addresses are 600 and you wish to exclude 519, instead you can use

```
index=indexer action=Null IP IN (10.34.67.31 , 87.90.32.11 ... so on)
```

Also, if you specific ranges of IP addresses you don't want, you can exclude or include them based on regex or wild-card.

Although, the above answer too is useful if you really have a huge list of IP addresses.